# I can't setup custom SSO for Dropbox Business

Tags: single-sign-on, dropbox, saml-2.0

I'm trying to set up the SSO login in my Dropbox business account. I've developed a custom Identity Provider named Ianum. In the Dropbox console, I set up:

- Identity Provider sign-in URL: https://alpha-id.ianum.com/SSO/SAML2/Redirect?idSamlIdp=saml_idp_2ottgAnc2sWHmAkiy6Mh
- Identity Provider sign-out URL: empty
- X.509 certificate:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDVTCCAj0CCB5f3a7UpFWQMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMG0xCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVT
MQ4wDAYDVQQIDAVUZXhhczEPMA0GA1UEBwwGQXVzdGluMRIwEAYDVQQKDAlJYW51
bSBJbmMxEjAQBgNVBAsMCUlhbnVjIEluYzEVMBMGA1UEAwwMaWQuaWFudW0uY29t
MB4XDTE5MTAwMTEzMjcwN1oXDTIzMDkzMDEzMjcwN1owbTELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMx
DjAMBgNVBAgMBVRleGFzMQ8wDQYDVQQHDAZBdXN0aW4xEjAQBgNVBAoMCUlhbnVt
IEluYzESMBAGA1UECwwJSWFudWMgSW5jMRUwEwYDVQQDDAxpZC5pYW51bS5jb20w
ggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQDKA0/7RBUZ+WR7NZvJu/hQ
KNIwheek29elh4jlzIk7of2ZmvOyYIz+5ualYf4SOlMopM3WpfYhZ+Vm2P07LnDQ
uxDxNX6lvq5l/vucpiNsbCbV/vLxPu6eswP7LdZ+Igt7beTyG8OUOlV5oXqjwVU6
iBSysNmyaOke48jn4rG8vSEBurKTnqBLLzuCXmZHnuU5tOVUrMLnQ9va7/yk8lWe
4SV0w/ncSDhAdtYHYiFee7wT4kOoiBHXeJKD+CoGTysw3lRjXfu9TuPE3TS3zj8f
ISHyYt1hVfqxaA84RIe7yqeRO+xYpMKGMtmXa/RHmFMBZJqc8WiLcfCuw+SsmIEj
AgMBAAEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAKkMLKqcMWP9XHC6sn6m5ec6wDz6QrFk
6SM0OmAn16PxMhH85vtWmyFESb7Tw3rQ4dwGjFGs2S27PEI0W+apzc+sX8vSSq4a
cVdQQBd/pm3YRgOiFilXgNQ4gyYDjuJVaq+AqbeBVA5kp0aYiwqeBKuPr6aHBR0y
Mqi2wpNKONEgM/hBK6UbcC9iJEIl9YUz+nCuPzyg1kPEZmEYQw+wNvAzrxACLg1m
a4wtuBKn81F+fSKyVuVx/Tn2V/u1qe2f8gMMtJO8lRgFuUNba4EI6Yz4jI6l2b8d
a4fj0/hWVOOG3AcGIrkVNAyatD4GnQPsz8AIauws14SIXuCHC+f/+DY=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

So if I go to dropbox.com, I click on `Login` and I type my email, Dropbox recognizes that the SSO is enabled and I'll be redirected to my Identity Provider. The Identity Provider authenticates me and I'm redirected back to Dropbox. The assertion generated is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<saml2p:Response
    xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ID="_2169143f2dbb462d91ca75ef03326849" InResponseTo="id-5d8425907fc84102b167bbaf380d5dc5" IssueInstant="2019-10-07T13:40:45.611826+00:00" Version="2.0">
    <saml2:Issuer
        xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://alpha-id.ianum.com/SSO/SAML2/Redirect?idSamlIdp=saml_idp_2ottgAnc2sWHmAkiy6Mh
    </saml2:Issuer>
    <saml2p:Status>
        <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"></saml2p:StatusCode>
    </saml2p:Status>
    <saml2:Assertion
        xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_0a2e10fb4e6245499bdb82d1e61f0d2f" IssueInstant="2019-10-07T13:40:45.611826+00:00" Version="2.0">
        <saml2:Issuer>https://alpha-id.ianum.com/SSO/SAML2/Redirect?idSamlIdp=saml_idp_2ottgAnc2sWHmAkiy6Mh</saml2:Issuer>
        <ds:Signature
            xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"></ds:SignatureMethod>
                <ds:Reference URI="#_0a2e10fb4e6245499bdb82d1e61f0d2f">
                    <ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></ds:Transform>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:Transform>
                    </ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></ds:DigestMethod>
                    <ds:DigestValue>8+OwpT3G8PO2JsuySxMlZ3cy/Dw=</ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>c9pBr1NM6voJ+nCymw1T8qXgFYBdqXLoDGVDwg6KLuQYZCxFjrJ8t+d65uV0tR5lGa65RmlVzWt+xrTk8mhvPbE2lVgttLkUcjVfD7VkjyVsOwhf80XTCa4EUOeckiU+o8aCfJvxQH158cHOfjRP5NIHHIhbWvSn0IvDUnnAVI8PieWCVqL7p6dBff/gDosb/NurBxluboC6tbDZ1NU6t3GxnikhG8C3Dd47G8HRF+W1comoHyd7VtPkbgIUJ2RCOx4MZ2OTI5qHWdh9hXsrVK1DMvB0frqzNoYKGGgQTKo53gywkcs81cKPvCiYSOlLZwOOk9DZG2vG564tirgwWw==</ds:SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo>
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </ds:Signature>
        <saml2:Subject>
            <saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">f.castelli@ianum.com</saml2:NameID>
            <saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                <saml2:SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="id-5d8425907fc84102b167bbaf380d5dc5" NotOnOrAfter="2019-10-07T13:55:45.611826+00:00" Recipient="https://www.dropbox.com/saml_login"></saml2:SubjectConfirmationData>
            </saml2:SubjectConfirmation>
        </saml2:Subject>
        <saml2:Conditions NotBefore="2019-10-07T13:37:45.611826+00:00" NotOnOrAfter="2019-10-07T13:55:45.611826+00:00">
            <saml2:AudienceRestriction>
                <saml2:Audience>Dropbox</saml2:Audience>
            </saml2:AudienceRestriction>
        </saml2:Conditions>
        <saml2:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2019-10-07T13:40:45.611826+00:00">
            <saml2:AuthnContext>
                <saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:unspecified</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>
            </saml2:AuthnContext>
        </saml2:AuthnStatement>
    </saml2:Assertion>
</saml2p:Response>
```

I'm generating the digest on this:

```xml
<saml2:Assertion
    xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_0a2e10fb4e6245499bdb82d1e61f0d2f" IssueInstant="2019-10-07T13:40:45.611826+00:00" Version="2.0">
    <saml2:Issuer>https://alpha-id.ianum.com/SSO/SAML2/Redirect?idSamlIdp=saml_idp_2ottgAnc2sWHmAkiy6Mh</saml2:Issuer>
    <saml2:Subject>
        <saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">f.castelli@ianum.com</saml2:NameID>
        <saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
            <saml2:SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="id-5d8425907fc84102b167bbaf380d5dc5" NotOnOrAfter="2019-10-07T13:55:45.611826+00:00" Recipient="https://www.dropbox.com/saml_login"></saml2:SubjectConfirmationData>
        </saml2:SubjectConfirmation>
    </saml2:Subject>
    <saml2:Conditions NotBefore="2019-10-07T13:37:45.611826+00:00" NotOnOrAfter="2019-10-07T13:55:45.611826+00:00">
        <saml2:AudienceRestriction>
            <saml2:Audience>Dropbox</saml2:Audience>
        </saml2:AudienceRestriction>
    </saml2:Conditions>
    <saml2:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2019-10-07T13:40:45.611826+00:00">
        <saml2:AuthnContext>
            <saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:unspecified</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>
        </saml2:AuthnContext>
    </saml2:AuthnStatement>
</saml2:Assertion>
```

And then I'm generating the signature on this:

```xml
<ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"></ds:SignatureMethod>
    <ds:Reference URI="#_0a2e10fb4e6245499bdb82d1e61f0d2f">
        <ds:Transforms>
            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></ds:Transform>
            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:Transform>
        </ds:Transforms>
        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></ds:DigestMethod>
        <ds:DigestValue>8+OwpT3G8PO2JsuySxMlZ3cy/Dw=</ds:DigestValue>
    </ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
```

The signature in the assertion is correct but Dropbox says: `Could not validate SAML Assertion`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The standard reason for this error is [usually](https://help.dropbox.com/accounts-billing/security/resolve-SAML-error) due to the X.509 certificate either having expired or it approaching the expiry date. I'd recommend you generate a new one and check the dates.

If it still fails contact Dropbox support, it could be something unique about your implementation of SSO.

Comment: The certificate is valid because it expires on 09/30/2023. I tried to ask for a new certificate but it's still failing. I'll try to contact Dropbox support to solve this problem.
I also tried to use my G Suite account as the Identity Provider and I compared the assertion generated by them and the assertion generated by Ianum. The only difference I noticed is the Issue Timestamp format but I can't find which standard I've to use. Do you know if there's a standard or something like that?

Comment: Maybe generate a certificate that expires on 09/09/2023 and see if that works, it could be based on the timestamp of it confusing the month/day and that it's viewing the 30th as the month which would be invalid.

Comment: I tested my certificate on this website https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html and I got the same result of Dropbox: the certificate is valid until September 30, 2023.

Answer (score 0):

That's your sign-in URL but is that also the entityID of your IdP? It's the entityID that's supposed to be encoded within the `<Issuer>` element.

Also, rsa-sha1 has been [officially insecure](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48289/how-secure-is-sha1-what-are-the-chances-of-a-real-exploit) for signatures for some time, and Dropbox may no longer support it. I would flip that to use rsa-sha256.

Comment: Is it a problem if I have the entityID and the sign-in URL that are the same? 
And thank you for the rsa-sha1 stuff, I'm going to change it.

Comment: I also updated the question adding the xml string on which I'm generating the signature

Comment: Well, the IdP looks at the Issuer element to respond. So if your entityId in the metadata that you uploaded to Google matches that, then it's no big deal. But if you used something else in the metadata that you uploaded / specified to Google then you're gonna have a bad time. Basically, double check that what you are asserting as your entity ID really is what you're including in the Issuer element.

Comment: Got it. Yeah, what I'm asserting as my entity ID is what I'm including in the Issuer element. I think that the problem is on the signature of the Assertion. Do you know what I have to include in the signature? I'm reading the SAML 2.0 official documentation but it doesn't say how to make that signature.

Comment: Not 100% certain. I specialize in middleware like Shib... less on the roll-your-own. This might help you though: https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/XSTJ2/xmlsectool+V2+Home generate an unsigned assertion with your code, pass it through xmlsectool, and see what the output is. That'll tell you how the Shib guys do their signing.